# Variable not changing properly when called in a Volley JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, android, variables, request, android-volley

I have a boolean function called `isAlreadyInDatabase(String email, String password)` which checks if an email address and a password are already present on a database (an excel file).

To do so, the method creates an `EmailAndPasswordGet` object and calls a `checkEmailAndPassword(email, password)` method. Here's the code:

```
public boolean isAlreadyInDatabase(String email, String password) {
    return new EmailAndPasswordGet(context).checkEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

Now the `EmailAndPasswordGet` code:

```
public class EmailAndPasswordGet {
private final Context context;

private String email;
private String password;

private static boolean successful;

private final JsonObjectRequest validEmailAndPasswordRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Costanti.URL_DB, null, response -> {
    try {
        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("values");
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray row = array.getJSONArray(i);
            if (row.get(4).equals(email) && row.get(5).equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("Match found!");
                successful = true;
                
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}, null);

public EmailAndPasswordGet(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    successful = false;
}

public boolean checkEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;

    Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
            .add(validEmailAndPasswordRequest
                    .setRetryPolicy(
                            new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                    Costanti.SOCKET_TIME_OUT,
                                    0,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)));

    System.out.println("Match: " + successful);

    return successful;
}
```

I used a boolean variable `successful` to know if something went wrong or if a match was found.

Now the problem: when I try to run my application (correct email and password) the console outputs this:

```
I/System.out: Match: false
I/System.out: Match found!
```

Theoretically, the `Match found!` message should appear **before** the other one. As you can see by the code when the request is running, it should output `Match found!`, change `successful = true` and then output `Match: true`. This doesn't happen.

As demonstrated the match is found, but then it just returns `false` which is not right. The only thing that comes to mind is that the `successful` variable just doesn't work between scopes or the request is delayed somehow so that it doesn't update the variable properly. I have no idea.

So what's wrong? Am I missing something on how requests work? Does the variable work this way? I just wanna know if a match was found or not, how can I do it?

Forgive me if I wrote the question badly, first time around here!

Have a great day, thank you! :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody it kinda does but I still can't figure out how to apply the solutions to my problem.